# test case incorrect for paranthesis checker code. For '(()' output sould be 'not balanced' but i'm getting 'balanced'

Tags: c++, string, stack

Given an expression string exp. Examine whether the pairs and the orders of `“{“,”}”,”(“,”)”,”[“,”]”` are correct in exp.
For example, the program should print `'balanced'` for `exp = “[()]{}{[()()]()}”` and `'not balanced'` for `exp = “[(])”`

Input

The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases.  Each test case consists of a string of expression, in a separate line.

Output

Print `'balanced'` without quotes if the pair of parenthesis is balanced else print `'not balanced'` in a separate line.

Constraints

```
1 ≤ T ≤ 100
1 ≤ |s| ≤ 105
```

Example

Input:

```
3
{([])}
()
([]
```

Output

```
balanced
balanced
not balanced
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //code
    int t;cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        string s;
        stack<char> st;
        int i=0,flag =1;
        getline(cin,s);
        int n = s.size();
        while(s[i] != '\0') {
            if((s[i] == '{') || (s[i] == '[') || (s[i] == '(')) {
                st.push(s[i]);
            }
            else if(!st.empty() && ((st.top() == '{' && s[i] == '}') || 
            (st.top() == '[' && s[i] == ']') || (st.top() == '(' && s[i] == ')'))) st.pop();
            else {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        (st.empty() && flag) ? cout<<"balanced\n" : cout<<"not balanced\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please include your input and output

Comment: This program is simple enough that you can step through the failing test case with a debugger and verify your assumptions.

Comment: I can reproduce it, `())` should result in "not balanced" and indeed it results in "not balanced": https://godbolt.org/z/Mn2hwr. There is a small misunderstanding somewhere...

Comment: sorry, changed the title now

Comment: I ran it and `(()` returned `"not balanced"`.  I had to include `<string>` for it to compile, and I hate the print-out line, but apart from that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stepping through your code with a debugger, the first time through the loop your string is empty.

This is because `cin >> t` stops reading at the newline character of the first line, and the first `getline(cin, s)` line receives an empty string.

Simply call `getline(cin, dummy_string)` after `cin >> t` to read the rest of the line, or switch your loop to use `cin >> s` instead.